# Strange behaviour of Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration::EnableDHCP?

Tags: c, windows, networking, wmi

My application has ablities to turn network adaptors of or enable them for either DHCP or static configuration. IP configuration is done via WMI Win32_NetworkApapterConfiguration class and disabling/enabling adapters is done via SetupApi for some reasons. Starting at the point where the adapter was enabled, I noticed following (Windows 7 SP1, 32bit):

EnableDHCP method return with error 84 (IP not enabled). So I thought I need to wait that property the "IpEnabled" becomes true and polled it every second - but it always returned false (BTW: I monitored the value using WMIC and could see that it has actually became true).

Next - in order to avoid and inifinite loop - I changed my "poll 'IpEnabled == true' loop" to jump out after 10 trials, and do the remaining stuff. And see: EnableDHCP succeeded (ret == 0), and also IpEnabled suddely became true.

**EDIT**

Situation 1:

```
int ret;

// ...

// Returns error 84
ret = wmiExecMethod(clsName, "EnableDHCP", true, objPath);

// ...
```

Situation 2:

```
int ret;

// ...

// Will never get out of this
while (!wmiGetBool(pWMIObj, "IPEnabled"))
{
    printf("Interface.IpEnabled=False\n");
    Sleep(1000);
}

// ... 

ret = wmiExecMethod(clsName, "EnableDHCP", true, objPath);
```

Situation 3:

```
int count = 10;
int ret;

// ...

// Will occur until count becomes 0
while (wmiGetBool(pWMIObj, "IPEnabled") && count--)
{
    printf("Interface.IpEnabled=False - remaining trials: %d\n", count);
    Sleep(1000);
}

// ... 

// After this "delay", EnableDHCP returns 0 (SUCCESS)
ret = wmiExecMethod(clsName, "EnableDHCP", true, objPath);

// wmiGetBool(pWMIObj, "IPEnabled") now returns true too...
```

Do you have any ideas what is going wrong here? Thanks in before for help.

Best regards
Willi K.

Comment: My crystal ball says that you forgot to re-run the query inside the loop.  Not much point in forcing us to guess when you can simply copy/paste your code into the question.

Comment: Some correction: "IpEnabled" is still false even after "EnableDHCP" succeeded, However, my current workaround is to call EnableDHCP until it succeeds for a limited number of retries. If anyone has a better idea, I will be happy to hear about it.

Answer (score 1):

The "real" problem behind this is that the Win32_NetworkApapterConfiguration::EnableDHCP method fails if the interface is not connected to a network (offline). The only way I found to configure the interface for DHCP is to modify the registry....